# Is initializing a variable with an uninitialized variable legal?

Tags: c++, initialization, language-lawyer

The following C++ code is legal:

```
char* ptr;
```

while the following is not (using an uninitialized variable is UB):

```
ptr++;
```

Will the following code:

```
char* ptr2 = ptr;
```

be legal or will it be undefined behavior?

Comment: I would say no, anything else than *writing to* an uninitialized variable (to initialize it) is normally undefined behavior. The wording of the Standard is probably a tad more obtuse of course.

Comment: using an uninitialized pointer may result in unpredictable and potentially disastrous outcomes., so for same reason `char* ptr2 = ptr;` will be illegal, causes Undefined behavioral. (*`not posting answer because I have no reference`*)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The declaration statement:

```
char* ptr2 = ptr;
```

will read the (uninitialized) value of `ptr`. It is UB, since the value of `ptr` is not defined.

Answer (score 6):

This is undefined for the same reason as post increment -- you don't have a defined basis to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

It is legal but the behavior is undefined since you don't know the content of `ptr` (most compilers will give you a warning).